# is it safe to use std::string functions in a thread? (c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

i want to make a thread in a dll that will make some web requests. in the thread now i use std::sting functions (c_str(), at(), find(), substr()) and (string + string). as i know the threads running asynchronously, and also i found out  if i call 1 function 2 times at the same time(1 from main program and 1 from thread) will cause problems/crash i guess because both using the same memory?

so now if i do many web requests very fast i crash sometimes. i think it's because using at the same time 2 times a std::string function. 
Also if this is maybe cause the problem is there any other way i can use for that work?

Comment: There are a few C-style string functions originating from the C library, like `std::strtok`, which have an internal static variable that maintains state across calls.  Functions that maintain their own internal state are not thread safe.

Comment: All functions in `std::string` are thread-safe. However, using multithreading, you have a bunch of other ways to shoot yourself in the foot. This may or may not show inside those functions, but it sure isn't caused by them. If you need advise with your code, consider codereview.stackexchange.com or, if you know it to be buggy, extract a [mcve] and post that here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Are you sharing the same `std::string` *object* across two threads?  If so (and that object is being modified by one thread while the other thread is also trying to use it), that would cause undefined behavior, unless you protect those accesses with some form of synchronisation (such as a *mutex*).

If OTOH the two threads are each operating on their own separate/private `std::string` objects, that won't cause a problem.